# Vector of structs - not seeing my definition for operator==

Tags: c++, vector, struct, operators

I have a class called Something that has two things: a string, and a vector of instructions. In that class, I want to define operator==. However, I get an error when I try to compile:

```
error: no match for ‘operator==’ in ‘* __first1 == * __first2’
```

This happened at the line where I am comparing the two vectors in Something using == (since vector has that conveniently defined, I would like to use it).

instruction is as follows:

```
struct instruction
{
    int instr;
    int line;

    bool operator==(const instruction& rhs)
    {
        return (instr == rhs.instr) && (line == rhs.line);
    }
};
```

I've searched for a solution to no avail. It seems that vector from the STL is not seeing the operator== I have defined for my struct when it's comparing these elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't shown the code that's actually failing, but most likely is a scenario such as this:

```
int main()
{
  vector <instruction> ins;
  vector <instruction>::const_iterator itA = /*...*/, itB = /*...*/;
  bool b = (*itA == *itB);
}
```

In this case, the problem is the fact that `operator==` is not `const`.  Change the declaration as follows:

```
bool operator==(const instruction& rhs) const
                                       ^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to add qualifier const to the operator ==.
Also you did not show how the vector is declared and used.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to make the operator=() method itself const.  You do that by adding 'const':

```
struct instruction
{
    int instr;
    int line;

    bool operator==(const instruction& rhs) const  // add const keyword here
    {
        return (instr == rhs.instr) && (line == rhs.line);
    }
};
```